# Visual Studio compiler 'syntax error' warnings on javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net, visual-studio, compiler-warnings

This question is just about warnings (application is working fine). I am using Visual Studio 2012, html5, framework 4.5 Asp.Net Web Application. We can observe this issue in aspx web page when in C# page part (aspx.cs) declaring:

```
public string EmployeeJson { get; set; }
```

and in page part (aspx) in javascript section we have:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var  employee = <%= EmployeeJson %>;
 </script>
```

After pressing "Rebuild Solution" in Error List tab we can see a Warning with description: "Syntax error". Compiler point with red underline on semicolon (without semicolon the red line will be under "var"). 
Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do this way

```
var employee=Object(<%= EmployeeJson %>);
```

Comment: Thanks. It works fine with array, but when I set there a simple string like "-1", then it starts treating this variable like an object. Therefore all equations like 'if(employee=="-1")' just don't work. How to fix it?

Comment: As i answer your question by seeing EmployeeJson which is obviously JSON format that's why give you that solution but as in case of string you may use String(). Like
var employee=String(<%= EmployeeJson %>);

Comment: Brilliant! You save my day. Now I have a clean code without warnings. Sorry I can't upvote your answer (need at least 15 reputation).

Comment: @romabr no problem up vote when you have reputation :p

Answer (score 1):

does it work if you do
var employee = "<%= EmployeeJson %>";

Comment: No.It throws critical error because the value is something like this ""-1""